# Saving hash generated by 'crypto' module to mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, hash

I'm having troubles to save, get and compare a crypto hash from mysql DB.

As mentioned, i'm using 'crypto' module in order to generate hash (that hash includes special charachters).

My table is using "utf8_unicode_ci" collation. 
Beacause of those special chars, I had troubles saving the hash to the DB.
So, I've tried to use this method:

```
exports.real_escape_string = function real_escape_string(str) {
    return str.replace(/[\0\x08\x09\x1a\n\r"'\\\%]/g, function (char) {
        switch (char) {
            case "\0":
                return "\\0";
            case "\x08":
                return "\\b";
            case "\x09":
                return "\\t";
            case "\x1a":
                return "\\z";
            case "\n":
                return "\\n";
            case "\r":
                return "\\r";
            case "\"":
            case "'":
            case "\\":
            case "%":
                return "\\" + char; // prepends a backslash to backslash, percent,
                // and double/single quotes
        }
    });
};
```

That worked and it did manage to save the hash to the DB, but for some reason when saving it to the DB it changes the hash itself.
I'm using the famous mysql module in order to access and perform actions on mysql database:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
```

What else can I try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use base64 when saving to the DB, and then decode when reading.

Comment: That's exactly what I did.. except the decode part (I'm converting the user input to base64 and comparing). How should i decode base64 back?

Comment: Both methods work. You can either convert user input to base64 and compare, or decode the DB base64 and compare to `hash(user_input)`. I personally find it better to decode, because the base64 in my mind is part of the DB layer logic, it's an implementation detail, so the code using the DB layer doesn't need to know about it.

Comment: var buf = new Buffer(str, 'base64');